# Twitch chat button is not picking up javascript set values

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, twitch

I am making a chrome extension where I need to add more functionality to the existing twitch chat.

The problem is, if I set a value of the textarea (the twitch chat text box) through javascript and then allow the user to hit enter or press the "Chat" button, the message being sent to the real time chat isn't the message I set through JS but only that is being sent that was typed by the user.

For example, first of all I am targeting the textarea by using the following code:

```
chat_textbox = document.getElementsByClassName('chat-input__textarea')[0].children[0].childNodes[0]
```

Now, let's say I set the value and the innerHTML of this textarea as follows:

```
chat_textbox.value = "Bitcoin"
chat_textbox.innerHTML = "Bitcoin"
```

Let's say these values are set when the user types in just "Bit", and not the whole word "Bitcoin". And then if the user tries to press enter key or click the "Click" button, even after the values of this textarea is set to "Bitcoin", but only "Bit" would be sent to the live chat.

Also, when the user either clicks or hovers over this textarea, the value set by me ("Bitcoin") is changed to just "Bit" again. So, I am assuming there's some functionality that keeps a record of what is being actually *typed* by the user and keeps on replacing it.

I want to prevent this default behavior to mess my custom functionality. What can I do?

Comment: Try triggering a `change` or `input` event on the `textarea` after you update it. I would assume that the Twitch UI is listening for an event like this to update state somewhere to read the value from the field, which is being missed out when you update the value programmatically.

Comment: Triggering `input` event seems to work! Thanks a lot for your quick response!

Comment: Glad it helped. I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the behaviour you describe I would assume that the Twitch UI is listening for an event in order to update state somewhere to then read the value from the field, which is being missed out when you update the value programmatically.

Therefore to fix this you could manually trigger a `change` or `input` event after you update the value of the `textarea`.

Comment: You are right! This worked! Thank you again!

Comment: Hello again! I am trying to do something similar on youtube as well. Again, I have changed, the 'href' values of all the anchor tags on a particular webpage but when I click, it redirects on the original href (even after the value has been changed). I tried dispatching a "onchange" and  "click" event after I assign new values but it didn't work. Same happens for facebook and twitter as well. Any ideas?